# The heading of the table of contents has "0" is front and I cannot find a way to remove it

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, formatting, titlesec

I must use a certain formatting mimicking a Microsoft Word Template. I created a Latex document for this purpose, and everything works fine, but for some mysterious reason, the standard command

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents }
\tableofcontents
```

generates a number 0 in front of the heading of the table of contents:

[image]

How can I obtain the standard behavior (no number)?

The code of the initial part of the document is

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,onecolumn]{report}

%%\include{def}  %% <-- where is 'def.tex'?

% FONTS
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\usepackage{graphicx,setspace,xcolor,titlesec,fancyhdr} % <-- need to load these packages

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[EL]{\textcolor{gray}{ATHENA: Adaptive high-speed 
                turbomachinery for mini-energy harvesting systems}}
\fancyfoot[ER]{\textcolor{gray}{\thepage}}

\definecolor{white}{rgb}{1.0, 1.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{NWOGreen}{RGB}{24,101,124}

\newcommand{\colorchapter}[1]{%
  \colorbox{white}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\thechapter\ #1}}}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{NWOGreen}}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\colorchapter}

\titleformat{\section}
{\bfseries\color{NWOGreen}}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\tableofcontents


\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Contact details}
\section{Main applicant}
\section{Co-applicant}
\section{Title}
\section{Keywords}

\clearpage
\chapter{Summary}
\section{Research summary}
\section{Utilisation summary}
\section{Summary NWO domain for AES website and online in ISAAC}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not self contained, what is in def, and you can remove any title page material as (1) we don't have the images and (2) It us irrelevant for the question. Additionally your example is not complete.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code to make it compilable and to make it generate the . Along the way, I eliminated the code for the title page since (a) the presence or absence of the title page doesn't affect the appearance of the ToC and (b) the code contains instructions such as `\HRule` which aren't defined. I also deleted the document class option `9.5pt` since it's not recognized by the `report` document class and hence gets ignored. Feel free to revert.

Comment: The problem is definitely coming from \titleformat, which is somehow replacing \chapter* with \chapter.

Comment: You are explicitly printing the chapter number in your `\colorchapter` macro. So it appears in both starred and unstarred variants.

Comment: What's your aim for the `\colorbox` macro? The chapter number printing code should go in the third mandatory argument of `\titleformat` (which is currently empty in your definition).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!
I took the code from other examples, but I am not so proficient to understand all that it does. Is \thechapter\#1 creating the problem? I cannot understand

Answer (score 1):

Define `\colorchapter` with two arguments and define also the `numberless` variant for `\chapter`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,onecolumn]{report}

% FONTS
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\usepackage{graphicx,setspace,xcolor,titlesec,fancyhdr} % <-- need to load these packages

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[EL]{\textcolor{gray}{ATHENA: Adaptive high-speed 
                turbomachinery for mini-energy harvesting systems}}
\fancyfoot[ER]{\textcolor{gray}{\thepage}}

\definecolor{white}{rgb}{1.0, 1.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{NWOGreen}{RGB}{24,101,124}

\newcommand{\colorchapter}[2]{%
  \colorbox{white}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{#1#2}}}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{NWOGreen}}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\colorchapter{\thechapter\quad}}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{NWOGreen}}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\colorchapter{}}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\bfseries\color{NWOGreen}}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents} % do you need this?
\tableofcontents


\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Contact details}
\section{Main applicant}
\section{Co-applicant}
\section{Title}
\section{Keywords}

\chapter{Summary}
\section{Research summary}
\section{Utilisation summary}
\section{Summary NWO domain for AES website and online in ISAAC}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code works, even I do not quite understand what all the commands do, by redefining \titleformat after \tableofcontents I obtained the wanted result

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,onecolumn]{report}

% FONTS
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\usepackage{graphicx,setspace,xcolor,titlesec,fancyhdr} % <-- need to load these packages

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[EL]{\textcolor{gray}{ATHENA: Adaptive high-speed 
                turbomachinery for mini-energy harvesting systems}}
\fancyfoot[ER]{\textcolor{gray}{\thepage}}

\definecolor{white}{rgb}{1.0, 1.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{NWOGreen}{RGB}{24,101,124}


\titleformat{name=\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{NWOGreen}}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}

\titleformat{\section}
{\bfseries\color{NWOGreen}}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\tableofcontents


\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\newcommand{\colorchapter}[1]{%
\colorbox{white}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\thechapter\ #1}}}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{NWOGreen}}
  {}
  {0pt}
 {\colorchapter}

\chapter{Contact details}
\section{Main applicant}
\section{Co-applicant}
\section{Title}
\section{Keywords}

\clearpage
\chapter{Summary}
\section{Research summary}
\section{Utilisation summary}
\section{Summary NWO domain for AES website and online in ISAAC}

\end{document}
```

If anyone can help making an elegant and cleaned up code, it would help many people, because we could provide a temaplate to our funding agency that at the moment offers only the possibility of using a MS Word template